# Does Oracle Database Express Edition 21c have GUI or a browser view on Windows?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle21c

I have downloaded and installed Oracle DB EX 21c on Windows and it seems the only way to interact with it is using the command prompt. Some older versions like 11g have a gui which for a student make it easier to understand.

Thank you

Comment: For a GUI client, try SQL Developer: https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/sqldev-downloads.html

Comment: As stated by @pmdba, SQL Developer is the tool you seem to be looking for.  However, I would challenge your assertion that it makes it "easier to understand".  My 40 years of working IT (25+ years working with oracle) has proven to me that working with the command line will force you to develop a better understanding of exactly what is what and how the pieces really fit together.  Much better for your professional education and career growth.